# Kotlin compose how to know when suspend function is finished?

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

This is the complete flow:

this is in the user profile:

```
.clickable {
         loginViewModel.onLogout()
         isLogin= false
   }
```

**isLogin** should be assign to false only when **doLogout** is finished
How can I run another function or code only when this function is done? Can I know when the function is finished?

this is from ViewModel():

```
fun onLogout() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                loginStatus = "out"
                getUserType = null
            }
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
                val token = it.result
                viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    try {
                        repo.doLogout(token)
                    }catch (exp: Exception){
                        println("FCM token error")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is from the repository:

```
suspend fun doLogout(token: String) {
        val userId = appService.currentUser!!.id
            realm.write {
                var user = query<UserInfo>("_id = $0", userId).first().find()
                if (user != null) {
                    user = findLatest(user)!!.also {
                        it.FCMToken.remove(token)
                    }
                    copyToRealm(user)
                }
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            realm.syncSession.uploadAllLocalChanges()
            appService.currentUser?.logOut()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Assuming `doLogout()` has been implemented correctly, so it doesn't launch background tasks, you do this correctly already.

Comment: it does do a "withContext(Dispatchers.Default)" is this an error?

Comment: I want to wait for all the function to finish, including background tasks or coroutines.

Comment: Suspending functions are by default executed sequentially. If you don't run anything using external/additional coroutine scopes, then the function returns only after it finished running all its code. Your current approach should be fine. Do you observe a different behavior or you just wanted to confirm if this guaranteed to work as expected?

Comment: Suspend functions are synchronous. Your code *has* to wait for it to return before execution continues, just like any other function. But like any other function, you could define it to internally start some other asynchronous task that it doesn't wait for before returning. Normally, you wouldn't do that when composing your suspend function.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to debug and in the middle of the logout function, isLogin will be assigned. After, doLogout continues...

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something wrong inside `doLogout` if I understand what you're saying correctly.

Comment: Probably yes, can someone of you help me with this? Could we chat somewhere or have a fast call? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can start by providing the code of your `doLogout()` if possible.

Comment: I have updated the question with the complete flow.

Comment: So as I said earlier, the problem is that you use `viewModelScope.launch()` which invokes the operation in the background. Make it a suspend function and invoke the code directly. Also, why initially did you ask about a suspending function? In year real example you call a non-suspend function.

Comment: So the best way is to make onLogout suspend? And dont use anymore viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO)?

Comment: I am in right path to solve this?

Comment: What a should use in user profile Composable to run the suspend function? GlobalScope.lunch{}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that works without errors.

This is my onLogout in LoginlView:

```
suspend fun onLogout(token: String, onCompletion: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        loadingLogout = true
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                repo.doLogout(token)
                onCompletion(true)
            } catch (exp: Exception) {
                println("FCM token error")
                onCompletion(false)
            }
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                loginStatus = "out"
                getUserType = null
            }
        }
        repo = RealmRepo()
        loadingLogout = false
    }
}
```

I use **onCompletion** to check when the logout is done

Since this function is suspended, I call **(from clickable())** a coroutine like this:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
   loginViewModel.onLogout(token!!) { logoutSuccessful ->
       if (logoutSuccessful) {
         context.getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    .edit().apply {
     putBoolean("isLoggedIn", false)
     apply()
              }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in `viewModel.onLogout()`, you're launching a new coroutine asynchronously instead of just making it a suspend function. A suspend function is synchronous. Launching a coroutine is asynchronous to the caller. You want this function to be synchronous, because you want to wait for it to finish.

You also need to get rid of `addOnCompleteListener` since that is also an asynchronous call. (You have an asynchronous call in another asynchronous call, inside a third nested asynchronous call since you launch another coroutine inside the listener!) This can be replaced with the `await()` suspend function call (since suspend functions are synchronous). If you get an unresolved reference and can't import the `await()` extension function, make sure you are using the `-ktx` version of the Firebase library in your dependencies.

You don't need `withContext` when you are calling a suspend function, you can remove that from your `repo.doLogout` call.

So change your ViewModel function to:

```
suspend fun onLogout() = withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    loginStatus = "out"
    getUserType = null
    try {
        val token = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.await()
        repo.doLogout(token)
    } catch (exp: Exception){
        println("FCM token error")
    }
}
```

I'm not positive if `= withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` is necessary above. Not enough familiar with Compose yet myself to know if it's safe to modify MutableState from any thread, so I just put that there defensively.

I'm not familiar with Realm, so I can't really comment on whether your repo function is done correctly.

Comment: By the way, assuming you are on Android, I would use logging instead of `println`.

Answer (score 0):

You can receive a callback lambda in your logout () function and invoke it when your async work is done. Although I kinda dislike that solution. The best solution is to expose a logoutEffect SharedFlow in your ViewModel, which your Composable collects to receive logout events.

Comment: Could you refactor my logout please?

Comment: @Cipri I could help you but I would need to see the code. If you don't mind, create a sample project in GitHub and post the link. We can collaborate on that project.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `isLogin` variable into your view model.

```
.clickable {
         loginViewModel.onLogout()
   }
```

```
val isLogin = mutableStateOf(true)

fun onLogout() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                loginStatus = "out"
                getUserType = null
            }
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
                val token = it.result
                viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    try {
                        repo.doLogout(token)
                        isLogin = false
                    }catch (exp: Exception){
                        println("FCM token error")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

put all your background tasks in your coroutine into an aysnc block assigned to a variable.  at the end of doing your tasks, return any value.  you can await this value in a runBlocking {} block to pause execution until logout is completed.

Comment: This would block the main thread to wait for IO. Don't do this!!!!

Comment: I know it does.  I suggested it to pause interaction with the app until logout is completed.  That would prevent other data being altered after it was sent.

Comment: The UI thread should never be blocked. Users hate it because it freezes all interaction with the phone and makes it seem like it has crashed, and it can cause the ANR error message to pop up. Google hates it because it makes their devices seem broken. Google Play almost certainly uses ANR stats to diminish apps in search results if they are guilty of doing this.

Comment: Logouts shouldn't take that long.

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest this solution for your case but for your question of "Can I know when the function is finished?", you may use invokeOnCompletion

```
    private var job: Job? = null
 
    job=viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                    loginStatus = "out"
                    getUserType = null
                }
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
                    val token = it.result
                    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        try {
                            repo.doLogout(token)
                        }catch (exp: Exception){
                            println("FCM token error")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    job!!.invokeOnCompletion {
    
    if (it is Exception) { //CancellationException
            Log.d("Job","Here handle exception")
        }else{
            Log.d("Job","Done Succesfully")
        }
     }
```

However ,instead, use function as paramater or val isLogin = mutableStateOf(true) as @DominicFischer replied